# Renaming SQL Server database from SQLCMD

Tags: sql-server, database, sqlcmd

How can I rename `AdventureWorksLT2008` database to `AdventureWorksLT2008_old` with its `.ldf` and `.mdf` files renamed as well?

I would like to do it from `sqlcmd`. It is a local server. I would like to do it with `-E` option. I did try googling but results didn't work for me. Can anyone suggest a tried method.

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 1):

a quick google search got [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/345942/Rename-a-Database-and-its-MDF-and-LDF-files-in-SQL) as the top result. All you have to do is to everything from sqlcmd( I am assuming you know how to use sqlcmd..)

```
-- Replace all MyDBs with the name of the DB you want to change its name
USE [MyDB];
-- Changing Physical names and paths
-- Replace all NewMyDB with the new name you want to set for the DB
-- Replace 'C:\...\NewMyDB.mdf' with full path of new DB file to be used
ALTER DATABASE MyDB MODIFY FILE (NAME = ' MyDB ', FILENAME = 'C:\...\NewMyDB.mdf');
-- Replace 'C:\...\NewMyDB_log.ldf' with full path of new DB log file to be used
ALTER DATABASE MyDB MODIFY FILE (NAME = ' MyDB _log', FILENAME = 'C:\...\NewMyDB_log.ldf');
-- Changing logical names
ALTER DATABASE MyDB MODIFY FILE (NAME = MyDB, NEWNAME = NewMyDB);
ALTER DATABASE MyDB MODIFY FILE (NAME = MyDB _log, NEWNAME = NewMyDB_log);
```